# Wrong python installation recognized by IDLE / or Anaconda not recognized by IDLE

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I am pretty new to Python and couple technical things are abstruse to me. I have installed Python 3 on a MacOS few weeks ago now. I have been using IDLE without any hassle so far, except when I tried to use the package `matplotlib`.

I found out I needed to install Anaconda, which I did. However, from IDLE I cannot import the package matplotlib, for the simple reason there is no module named `matplotlib`. After much investigation, I realized that I can find the module launching python from the terminal.

In the terminal, I start with the command `python3` to launch python, then `import matplotlib.plot as plt` runs fine without error, indicating the module is there! Then I input `plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])` to draw a simple graphic, and display it with `plt.show()`. It does show a window with the simple graphic!

This leads me to believe the problem comes from IDLE, and more precisely that there might be two python 3 installed which are the one the terminal calls and the one IDLE calls. How could I proceed further to be able to use `matplotlib` from IDLE itself?

Sincerely,
Olivier

Comment: Yes, it seems you have 2 python installs. IDLE is not using the python where you have installed matplotlib. The two solutions would be to (1) install IDLE for the anaconda environment where you already have matplotlib installed and use that one from now on, (2) Install matplotlib for the python where you are using IDLE to date.

Comment: I made it work, thanks to you! So it turns out IDLE is already installed with Anaconda. To run it on Mac you have to enter `idle3` in the terminal. I'll try to see on my end if I can uninstall the other Python/IDLE, and make a shortcut to the IDLE used by Anaconda. Thank you. It seems that you can download Anaconda, and it will install Python and IDLE on its own.